# Get Help Tuning This Query Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

It is really slow when using the website but when I try to run the exact same query directly in SQL Management Studio, it is quite fast.

Actual Execution Plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkKs2Ad8q

Comment: I would suggest to start from this article https://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue when away once I set the maximum rows to a static value. Perhaps it wasn't being optimized before.

```
    SELECT 
    b.ID,
    a.ID AS 'AuctionId',
    au.UserName,
    a.Name,
    b.MaxBidAmount,
    b.CurrentBidAmount,
    b.BidDateTime,
    b.Info
FROM Bids b
JOIN Auctions a on a.ID = b.AuctionID
JOIN AuctionGroups ag on ag.ID = a.AuctionGroupID
JOIN AspNetUsers au on au.Id = b.UserId
JOIN Parties p on p.Id = ag.PartyId
WHERE (p.DomainId = @domainId OR @domainId IS NULL)
AND (b.AuctionID = @auctionId OR @auctionId IS NULL)
ORDER BY b.ID DESC
OFFSET @startRowIndex ROWS
FETCH NEXT @maximumRows ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Your "optional parameter" approach will effectively kill the use of any index. If the performance is very important, then adding "OPTION (RECOMPILE)" might help. If this query is run very often, you could consider writing seperate queries to get rid of the "OR @var IS NULL" approach.